# How to read specific column in excel using c# and get the number of occurrences of different words in that column

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I want to find the number of occurrences of different words in column H using C# and ignore the null values. Later, I have to display the output in List box. I am using the Microsoft.Office.Interlop.Excel reference to open workbook and access the first worksheet.

I tried the following code :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("ABC.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


        Excel.Range bColumn = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns[4, Type.Missing].Columns.Count;


    List<string> dataItems = new List<string>();

    foreach (object o in bColumn)
    {

        Excel.Range row = o as Excel.Range;
        string s = row.get_Value(null);
        dataItems.Add(s);

    }
    listBox1.DataSource = dataItems;
        xlWorkbook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorksheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkbook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }
```

Please help me out with the code and suggest the fastest possible approach as the worksheet contains more than a thousand rows.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! 
Your question is already quite good. You can make it even better if you described how the code you posted behaves and what you would expect it to do.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you want to find all values in column C then:

```
object[] columnValue = xlWorksheet.Range["C"].Values2;
```

the columnValue will be the values in the excel.

So it would be a lot faster if you do it in memory, you can first convert it to a string list using `columnValue.Select(a=>a == null ? null : a.ToString()).ToList()` then you will be able to do all sort of logic such as using Distinct to get the distinct values, count to get the occurence and so on.

Comment: Good answer, just a little remark: a value of cell can be null, so you need to check it bebore .ToString(). Like columnValue.Select(a=>a == null ? null : a.ToString()).ToList() or columnValue.Select(a=>a?.ToString()).ToList() in c# 6.0

Comment: Oh Thank you, I've modified my answer

Comment: I'm getting this exception Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC on ' object[] columnvalues = xlWorksheet.Range["L"].Value2;'